# Custom Bootstrapper created using wix3.6 is not unistalling the msi

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I'm installing my msi package (my.msi) from custom managed bootstrapper
created using wix3.6 burn, the bootstrapper first installs a few prerequisite
packages and then installs my.msi.

The installation is working properly , but there is an issue with Uninstallation.
On uninstallation the bootstrapper closes without uninstalling anything, on checking the logs
the bootstrapper is logging the plan as:

**[1C10:2D80][2013-05-14T16:22:26]i201: Planned package: *my*, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister**

I'm calling **Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall)** in my managed code for uninstalling the application.

Im not seeing any other relevant information in the log file.

Does any one have any suggestions?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i've finally found the solution from this link

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-uninstall-Burn-bundle-td7579345.html

I've specified  ExitCode Behavior=”scheduleReboot”  for one of my pre-requiiste packages.